# how to make kafkaproducer to continuously run

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have written kafkaproducer in java to read logs . But after reading logs process is getting finished , how can I make kafkaproducer to continuously run.I dont want kafkaproducer to get stopped after reading logs.

Comment: Let me know if below answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Did you have a look into Kafka-Connect: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.1/connect/index.html It should provide what you want without even writing the code by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The logic is not related to Kafka but you need to continuously listen to the file for data as follows:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("/path/to/log.txt"));

    String line = null;
    while (true ) {
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            //wait till more data is appended to file
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        else {
            //send data to Kafka
            producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", "my-key", line));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Kafka-Log Appender to re-direct the logs to the central broker.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#KafkaAppender